# show notification on tab bar android

Tags: android

I am developing an android app which has tabbar in it one tab is notification . I have to display the number of notifications that are pending to that user i want to display the number of pending request is to be displayed on the icon.

me having an activity of notification which shows number of notifications pending i need to put that count in tabbar.Icon of that tab is one square & i want to put digit to that square but i am not able to do that is there any notifiaction api which gives me that count also put in that any viewgroup.

thnx for any help...............

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility, wich works for sure (I tried it):
use [`TabSpec.setIndicator(View)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.TabSpec.html#setIndicator%28android.view.View%29). You can set whatever `View` you like for the Tab-Header. This should allow you to style the header however you want.

Try this example code:

```
public class TabTest extends TabActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); // The activity TabHost
        TabHost.TabSpec spec; // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
        Intent intent; // Reusable Intent for each tab
        // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, MyActivity.class);

        // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
        spec = tabHost
                .newTabSpec("artists").setIndicator(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tablayout, null))
                .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
    }
}
```

and create a layout called `tablayout`. Put whathever you like in this layout (I took a clock for a quick demo). Also you have to create the `MyActivity` containing something that should be displayed when your tab is shown.

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of Tab]

Comment: thanks for rply.in tablayout which you have mention i am having a textview & i need to assign value to that textview dynamically...

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of **How to add a badge in tab**

chat_tab.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="0dip" 
    android:layout_height="64dip"
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="-3dip" 
    android:layout_marginRight="-3dip" 
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/tab_indicator" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/chat_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/chat_icon"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/new_notifications" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/chat_icon"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/chat_icon"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:textSize="8sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_dark"
        android:background="@drawable/badge"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/chat"
        style="@android:attr/tabWidgetStyle"
        android:textColor="@android:color/tab_indicator_text"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

This is **badge.xml** (red circle for notifications background),TextView id:new_notifications background

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="oval" >

    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#FFFFFF" />

    <corners android:radius="10dp"/>

    <padding android:left="2dp" />

    <solid android:color="#ff2233"/>

</shape>
```

Then in the code you can simply do

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View chatTab = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_tab, null);

        tvNewNotifications = (TextView) chatTab.findViewById(R.id.new_notifications);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(MainTab.this, Chat.class);
        tabSpec = tabHost
                .newTabSpec("chat")
                .setIndicator(chatTab)
                .setContent(intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
```

As you can see my Relative Layout has a background `@drawable/tab_indicator` the **tab indicator.xml** is the framework's standard drawable of the tab,which i got from the sdk,i suggest you should also get it from the folder of the api in sdk as you also need to copy some images from the drawable folders,you can find it 
**your_sdk_drive:\sdk\platforms\android-8**

Comment: could you elaborate on which files need to be copied over from the Android SDK folder?  I can see the tab_indicator.xml file, but I am unsure of which others are required for this.

Comment: @Phil if you open `tab_indicator.xml` you will notice it's referencing some other drawables which you can find from the standard `mdpi`, `hdpi` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

How about overriding the `dispatchDraw` method of the [TabWidget](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabWidget.html)? You can there use the drawing-api to draw the number onto the (already painted) tab-header.

Comment: Provide us with the code and we might be able  help you. Open a new question.

Comment: as similar to badge in iphone i want in android